# How do I process an image using ImageResizer and upload it to Azure storage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, kendo-ui, imageresizer

I'm using the ImageResizer nuget package in my MVC Application to resize an uploaded image and convert it to a JPG.  This image should then be uploaded to my Azure storage account.  I am receiving an error when I try to upload an image file of:

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.jpg'
>   is denied

So, I've wired something up wrong, but I want to make sure I'm actually doing this correctly.  Here is my code:

**CarController**

```
public ActionResult CarImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase CarImage, string id)
{
    //Connect to Azure
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("cardata_AzureStorageConnectionString"));

        //Process the Image
        try
        {
            //Create Blob Client
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //Retrieve a reference to a container
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("car-" + id);

            //Process Image
            ImageJob image = new ImageJob(CarImage, blobContainer + ".<ext>",
                new Instructions("width=500&format=jpg;mode=max"));

            //Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            try
            {

                blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {                  
                image.Build();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                //Upload to Azure
                CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(CarImage.FileName);
                blob.UploadFromStream(CarImage.InputStream);
                CarImage.InputStream.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }           
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
.Name("CarImage")
.Multiple(false)
.Validation(validation => validation.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".gif", ".jpg", ".png" }))
.Events(e => e
    .Upload("onFileSync")
    .Remove("onFileSync"))
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("CarImageUpload", "Car")
        .Remove("CarImageRemove", "Car")
        .AutoUpload(true)))
```

I think the way I've wired this up is looking for my Azure storage on my local disk, I'm not sure how I can ensure it's looking to Azure instead.  Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not related to uploading to Azure storage.

See this statement

```
 ImageJob image = new ImageJob(CarImage, blobContainer + ".<ext>",
            new Instructions("width=500&format=jpg;mode=max"));
```

The second parameter of `ImageJob` is the destination to create the resized image.

So the method is to create a image named `blobContainer + ".<ext>"` i.e. `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.jpg` at IIS working directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`.

To access `C:\Program Files (x86)`, we need to run IDE as administrator, or we'll get the error `Access to the path ... is denied`.

Instead of running as administrator, you can write your resized image to MemoryStream.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
ImageJob image = new ImageJob(CarImage, memoryStream,
            new Instructions("width=500&format=jpg;mode=max"));
```

If I understand it correctly, you actually want to upload this resized image to Azure storage. Just change `blob.UploadFromStream(CarImage.InputStream);` to

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
blob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
```